# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot API using the Spring Data REST framework (dependencies inherited from spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.0.RELEASE). I'm attempting to do a PUT or PATCH request to update an entity and neither seem to work, throwing the following error message:

> [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

The entity I am trying to update has the following structure:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA")
    private Set<EntityB> entitiesB;
}
```

where BaseEntity has the ID and auditing info.

I am making a PUT/PATCH request to the following path:

> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/entitiesA/the_uuid

with the body payload as

> { "name": "new name" }

Since it was a stack overflow error, my first thought was something recursive is happening. I commented out the Set< EntityB > field (along with the @OneToMany annotation) and I still encountered the error. Has anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: What database are u using? Seems like a transaction commit error relates with db.

Comment: Also, u need to post the whole trace stack to see exactly in which line of code this error happens.

Comment: It's a MySQL RDS instance (Version 5.7.22) hosted on AWS. For the development environment it connects via SSH tunnel.

Comment: Here's a link to the stack trace: https://pastebin.com/WWVb4C12
I've noticed com.api.config.AuditorAwareConfiguration.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareConfiguration.java:27) gets called over and over again, which is this line of code: userDao.findByUsername(username);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was to do with the way I implemented the AuditorAware< T > interface. The userDao method I was using was causing a recursive call. I still don't know why it was happening, but looking at [this forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/106312-spring-data-jpa-infinite-loop-when-updating-but-not-saving-an-auditable-object), I changed the implementation of getCurrentAuditor() from:

```
@Override
public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {
    String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
    return Optional.ofNullable(user);
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public Optional<User> getCurrentAuditor() {
    User auditor = null;
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            auditor = (User) principal;
        }
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(auditor);
}
```

and everything works as expected.

Comment: in this case createdBy not works but LastModifiedBy Works