# Spring boot JPA update failed

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

JPA Repository update failed.

```
following code of service not works. insert works

 spring boot 2.1.7

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public Employee updateEmployee(Employee emp, long id) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Repository emp" + emp.getPlantModel() + " id " + id);
    // return employeeRepository.save(emp);
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
    System.out.println("plant make" + emp.getPlantMake());
    System.out.println("emo is present" + employee.isPresent());
    if (employee.isPresent()) {
        Employee newEntity = employee.get();
        newEntity.setPlantMake(emp.getPlantMake());
        newEntity.setPlantModel(emp.getPlantModel());
        System.out.println("updating employee entity");
       

        return  employeeRepository.save(newEntity);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

insert works, jpa update throws an exception without any significant reason

entity class as follows I have connected to postgreSQL

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "emp_id", columnDefinition = "serial")
private long empId;

@Column(name = "plant_make")
private String plantMake;
```

looking for solution with spring boot 2.17

Comment: your save  object must contain an existing id in the database otherwise it will not work.check if id is exist in the modified object

Comment: Yes id is set below is the exception    2019-10-11 16:06:38.479 ERROR 3144 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [java.lang.StackOverflowError]
2019-10-11 16:06:38.481 DEBUG 3144 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)

java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
 at

Comment: looks your saving method leaking memory(StackOverflowError),this may be update method trying to update recursively..as a example  class A contains one instance of the B class, while, the B class contains one instance of the A class. this may happen because of db relationship.you have to check it carefully

Comment: this class connected User class as below  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "tbl_users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id"))
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "users", allowSetters = true)
    public Set<UserRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

Comment: I removed all dependencies 2019-10-14 11:47:25.019 DEBUG 6392 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663498/2931908

Comment: I have changed the JPA auditor to following User auditor = null;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                auditor = (User) principal;
            }
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(auditor);  insert failed but the update work now